# Shiny only uses the first item of selectInput when multiple = TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to use the value(s) of `input$levels` in the plot as the title but `selectInput` is only displaying the first value when multiple are selected. The plot itself changes in the correct way, which means shiny knows that multiple levels are selected.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

test_data <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 100, 10),
                        y = seq(1, 100, 10),
                        level = rep(c(1, 2), 5))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("levels",
                  "Include level(s):",
                  selected=1,
                  choices=c(1, 2),
                  multiple=TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(test_data %>% 
             filter(level %in% input$levels), aes(x, y)) + 
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle(paste("Including level(s):", input$levels))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How does one access all values of `selectInput` when multiple are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input$levels` contains a vector of your selected items. To make them appear in the title of your graph, you can do:

```
  ggtitle(paste("Including level(s):", paste(input$levels,collapse=', ')))
```

Hope this helps!